# Why doesn't range() return a list?

Tags: python, list, range

I ran into some problems when using the `range()` function to create `list`s.
Doing some experimenting, I get the following:

```
>>> isinstance([], list)
True
>>> isinstance(range(10), list)
False
```

Also, reading its documentation:

```
>>> print(range.__doc__)
range(stop) -> range object
range(start, stop[, step]) -> range object

Return a virtual sequence of numbers from start to stop by step.
```

I currently do have a workaround using `list(range())`, but the question still remains. What is a virtual sequence of numbers?

Comment: @tyteen4a03 - Not exactly.  `range` returns a lazy sequence of type `range`.  Its items are computed on-demand.  But you can reuse `range` objects while iterators are a one-time use (once you iterate over them, they are exhausted).

Comment: @tyteen4a03: no, it does **not** return an iterator. It is iterable, but it is a *sequence*, not an iterator.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#range

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A `range()` object calculates numbers *on demand*, e.g. when iterated over or when you try to access specific indices:

```
>>> r = range(2, 80, 3)
>>> len(r)
26
>>> r[15]
47
>>> 42 in r
False
>>> r[:10]
range(2, 32, 3)
```

It is a sequence because the object supports membership testing, indexing, slicing and has a length, just like a list or a tuple. But, unlike a list or a tuple, it doesn't actually contain all integers in the sequence in memory, making it *virtual*.

When you call `list()` on a `range()` object, you are creating a new sequence containing all the integers that are in the range, but you are now storing all those integers:

```
>>> r_list = list(r)
>>> r_list
[2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 17, 20, 23, 26, 29, 32, 35, 38, 41, 44, 47, 50, 53, 56, 59, 62, 65, 68, 71, 74, 77]
```

That's a sequence too, but it takes more memory as all integers are now produced up front, wether you'll use them or not. So a list or a tuple is a *concrete* sequence.

Using the [`sys.getsizeof()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof), we can calculate how much memory each object uses:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getsizeof(r)
48
>>> sys.getsizeof(r_list) + sum(sys.getsizeof(i) for i in r_list)
1072
```

The list object uses 22 times the memory; that's because it contains 26 integer objects.

And to address the comment on your question, `range()` objects are **not** [iterators](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typeiter). Iterators produce values one by one on demand, but cannot be indexed, they produce all values just *once* and they do not have a length. You can produce an iterator from a `range()` object with the [`iter()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter):

```
>>> iter(r)
<range_iterator object at 0x10aea23f0>
>>> r_iter = iter(r)
>>> len(r_iter)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: object of type 'range_iterator' has no len()
>>> list(r_iter)
[2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 17, 20, 23, 26, 29, 32, 35, 38, 41, 44, 47, 50, 53, 56, 59, 62, 65, 68, 71, 74, 77]
>>> list(r_iter)
[]
```

but once exhausted, the iterator won't produce the same range again.

All of the above applies mainly to Python 3; in Python 2 the type is called [`xrange()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#xrange-type), where it is more limited in its abilities (it doesn't support slicing and can only handle integers < `sys.maxint`).